# Symfony login success redirect to change password screen

Tags: symfony

Admin generate user then user first time login i want to redirect user to change password.

I have google but there are no any post found that make this fix.

Below i have attached service.yml and loginsuccessListener file code.

**service.yml**

```
services:               
    fos_user.security.interactive_login_listener:
        class: OnlineCare\MarketingWebBundle\EventListener\LastLoginListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
        arguments: ['@fos_user.user_manager','@router','@service_container']
```

**LastLoginListiner.php**

```
namespace OnlineCare\MarketingWebBundle\EventListener;

use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\UserEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\SecurityEvents;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class LastLoginListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    protected $userManager;
    private $router;
    private $container;

    public function __construct(UserManagerInterface $userManager, UrlGeneratorInterface $router, ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->userManager = $userManager;
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FOSUserEvents::SECURITY_IMPLICIT_LOGIN => 'onImplicitLogin',
            SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN => 'onSecurityInteractiveLogin',
        );
    }

    public function onImplicitLogin(UserEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getUser();

        $user->setLastLogin(new \DateTime());
        $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
    }

    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();

        if(empty($user->getLastLogin())){

            $url = $this->router->generate('fos_user_change_password');
            **return $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($url));**

        } elseif ($user instanceof UserInterface) {
            $user->setLastLogin(new \DateTime());
            $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try directly `return new RedirectResponse($url)` ?

Comment: Start by taking out the event and method arguments from your subscriber tag.  Then add some die statements and verify the listener is getting called as expected.

Comment: @Mcsky, thanks for replay. But this does not direct redirect to url from event. In my case there is break flow and imediatly redirect to url. If user is new then on success login redirect to change_pass route.